# Move Typescript Project to VSCode

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2017

I started out my project using the Typescript HTML Application Template project template. It worked pretty well and created a project for me. However, I wish to migrate to using VSCode, but the problem I'm having is finding out which switches and compiler options the project uses for the "tsc" command. I see it referenced in the .csproj, but I don't know exactly how it's interacting with it. It doesn't seem to have created a tsconfig or anything, so how does the typescript compiler know what to do?

TL;DR, where does Visual Studio keep the typescript compiler options.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you right-click on the project and select "Properties" there is a TypeScript compile tab on the bottom left. This is a friendly view over the configuration in the project XML.

You can extract these into a .tsconfig within Visual Studio. Once a .tsconfig is detected, the project settings no longer apply.

Once you have a working .tsconfig set up, you should be able to move easily to VS Code.

In Visual Studio 2015 some projects don't have a project XML file, in which case you can almost bet your config is equivalent to:

```
tsc app.ts --target ES5
```

Comment: Perfect, I added the tsconfig manually and messed around with config options for a bit and it works now. Thanks so much!